# WPF MVVM Pattern, need to send objects from one viewmodel to another one

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

Hi I have 3 ObservableCollections of a custom type in Viewmodel lets call it ViewmodelA and I need to send those collections to ViewmodelB. I tried to register a method that returns  a List of the 3 ObservableCollections using MessengerInstance but it is complaining that it is expecting a return type of void.

Keeping the mvvm pattern in mind what would be the best way of getting these colllections over to ViewModelB?

Btw I am using mvvm-light

this is the method i made to return the lists:

```
private List<ObservableCollection<Column>> RetrieveFilters(Column col)
{
    List<ObservableCollection<Column>> Out = new     List<ObservableCollection<Column>>
    {
        _manuColumns,
        _pnColumns,
        _nounModColumns
    };

    return Out;
}
```

then I tried to register the method with

```
 MessengerInstance.Register<Column>(this, RetrieveFilters);
```

the error I get is

> `List<ObservableCollection<Column>> PropertyViewModel.RetrieveFilters(Column)` 
>   has the wrong return type

Comment: well the obvious way would be to inject those observables into the viewmodels when you create them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your messenger approach is good, if you are using mvvm light , you should implement like this

```
class MyMessage
 {

      ObservableCollections col1 {get;set;}
      ObservableCollections col2 {get;set;}
      ObservableCollections col3 {get;set;}

    public MyMessage(ObservableCollections col1, ObservableCollections col2, ObservableCollections col3)
    {
       this.Col1 = col1;
       this.Col2 = col2;
       this.Col3 = col3;
     }
 }

class viewmodelA
 {
    void someFunc()
     {
       Messenger.Default.Send(new MyMessage (collection1, collection2, collection3);
     }
 }

class viewmodelB
 {
      viewmodelB()
      {
        Messenger.Default.Register<MyMessage > (this, message => DoSomething(message);
      }

      public void DoSomething(MyMessage message)
         {
             //use your collections
          }
 }
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot! that worked I never would have came up with this and almost seems backwards but it works perfectly. Thanks again

Comment: you are welcome, it is one of the solution to handle obects across multiple view models, you could also inject them as dependency if items are to be modified by two or more view models at the same time